# How to update react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a list of results from my search output. Each result has an `onclick` function. I want to display each of the results that the user clicks, and for now I can add each result that the user clicks to an array using this function:

```
let selectedData = []

function addFunc(resultdata){
    console.log(resultdata)
    selectedData = [...selectedData, resultdata]
    console.log(selectedData)
  };
```

I'm new to React, but I know this isn't the right way and I might have to use states or react hooks. The problem is that because I am using `Elasticsearch` to output the results, my results are in a function, not the main class. Like this:

```
class Search extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ReactiveBase
          app="datataglist"
          credentials="mRgWyoKGQ:f47be2a6-65d0-43b6-8aba-95dbd49eb882"
          url="https://scalr.api.appbase.io"
          >
              <DataSearch
              componentId="search"
              dataField={[
                  "maker_tag_name",
                  "maker_tag_name.autosuggest",
                  "maker_tag_name.keyword"
                ]}
                fieldWeights={[6, 2, 6]}
                fuzziness={1}
                highlightField={["maker_tag_name"]}
                placeholder="Search Tag Name"
                style={{
                    marginBottom: 20
                }}
                title="Maker Tag Name"
                />
                <Row gutter={16}>
                    <Col span={8}>
                        <MultiList
                            componentId="system"
                            dataField="system.keyword"
                            queryFormat="or"
                            size={100}
                            sortBy="asc"
                            style={{
                            marginBottom: 20
                            }}
                            title="System"
                        />
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={8}>
                        <MultiList
                            componentId="grouping"
                            dataField="grouping.keyword"
                            size={100}
                            style={{
                            marginBottom: 20
                            }}
                            title="Grouping"
                        />
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={8}>
                        <MultiList
                            componentId="unit"
                            dataField="units.keyword"
                            size={100}
                            style={{
                            marginBottom: 20
                            }}
                            title="Unit"
                        />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <SelectedFilters /> 
                  <ReactiveList
                    componentId="results"
                    dataField="_score"
                    pagination={true}
                    react={{
                        and: ["system", "grouping", "unit", "search"]
                    }}
                    size={10}
                    noResults="No results were found..."
                    renderItem={RenderItem}
                     />
          </ReactiveBase>
          <div>
          </div>
          </div>
      );
  }
}

function getNestedValue(obj, path) {
    const keys = path.split(".");
    const currentObject = obj;
    const nestedValue = keys.reduce((value, key) => {
      if (value) {
        return value[key];
      }
      return "";
    }, currentObject);
    if (typeof nestedValue === "object") {
      return JSON.stringify(nestedValue);
    }
    return nestedValue;
  }


  function RenderItem(res, triggerClickAnalytics) {
    let { unit, title, system, score, proposed, id } = {
      title: "maker_tag_name",
      proposed: "proposed_standard_format",
      unit: "units",
      system: "system",
      score: "_score",
      id: "_id"
    };
    title = getNestedValue(res, title);
    system = getNestedValue(res, system);
    unit = getNestedValue(res, unit);
    score = getNestedValue(res, score);
    proposed = getNestedValue(res, proposed);
    id = getNestedValue(res, id);

    const resultdata = {id, title, system, unit, score, proposed}

      return (
        <Row
          onClick={triggerClickAnalytics}
          type="flex"
          gutter={16}
          key={res._id}
          style={{ margin: "20px auto", borderBottom: "1px solid #ededed" }}
        >
          <Col style={{ width: "360px" }}>
            <h3
              style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: title || "Choose a valid Title Field"
              }}
            />
          </Col>
          <div style={{ padding: "20px" }} />
          <Col>
              <p
              style={{ fontSize: "1em", width: "300px" }}
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: system || "Choose a valid Description Field"
              }}
              />
          </Col>
          <div style={{ padding: "10px" }} />
          <Col>
          <p
              style={{ fontSize: "1em" }}
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: unit || "-"
              }}
            />
          </Col>
          <div style={{ padding: "10px" }} />
          <Col style={{ minWidth: "120px" }}>
            <p
              style={{ fontSize: "1em", width: "300px"}}
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: proposed || "Choose a valid Description Field"
              }}
            />
          </Col>
          <div style={{ padding: "10px" }} />
          <Col>
            <p
              style={{ fontSize: "1em"}}
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: Math.round(score) || "Choose a valid Description Field"
              }}
            />
          </Col>
          <Col>
              <Button
                shape="circle"
                icon={<CheckOutlined />}
                style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}
                onClick={()=> {addFunc(resultdata)}}
              />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      );
  }
```

Basically, my `ReactiveList` component is what shows the results. This calls the `RenderItem` function, which is what displays the data on the screen. In my function, I have a list called `resultdata`, which contains all the data I need when each result is clicked on. This works, but I need it to display on the screen.

I can't use state, because I have a function. And I can't use hooks because it isn't the main function. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other alternative to this?

Even if you can't provide a complete answer, I would appreciate any tips on which direction I should look towards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

state is async so it wont update like this:

```
function addFunc(resultdata){
    console.log(resultdata)
    selectedData = [...selectedData, resultdata]
    console.log(selectedData)
  };
```

and you are using a class so you can't `useHooks` but `setState` takes a callback as second argument

```
function addFunc(resultdata){
    console.log(resultdata)
    this.setState({selectedData: [...selectedData, resultdata]}, () => console.log(selectedData))
  };
```

so if you continue using a `Class` approach this will allow you to use `setState` and utilize the callback in it

there is a callback available too in hooks but it doesn't work quite the same

Comment: How can I display the information on screen and let it update? Right now, it shows on the console but I can't display it on the screen.

Comment: @DevelowebCo specifically what do you want to show?

Comment: A list (<ul>) of each of the results that the user clicks on. Each time the user clicks, in the console, a new object with 'id, title, unit, etc.' is added to the list. I want to display this data on the screen. For now, displaying anything, like the 'id' of each selected result would be great.

Comment: you need to map over the state you have set. focus on setting the state correctly to an array. then do `this.state.myState.map((item) => <div>{item} </div>)`

Comment: The problem that because my function is outside the class, I can't call it using `this`. And if you can, could you please also tell me what to write in my Class so that I can use the state? Just changing my function isn't working.

Comment: move the function into the class?

Comment: I did that, but I am still calling the `addFunc` function from within my `renderItem` function, so I can't call it using `this`. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @DevelowebCo yes change it to an arrow function like this. from: `function addFunc(resultdata){...}` to `const addFunc = (resultdata) => {...}`. does that make sense/work?

Comment: nope, it still didn't work, as `this` was still undefined. The function isn't called at all. However, I really appreciate your help so I've accepted your answer. If you can, please take a look at my updated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455038/how-to-call-function-in-parent-component-from-the-child-component.

Comment: Yes will take a look soon mate!

Comment: @DevelowebCo if you ask a new question I can try and help you there. also if you include a codesandbox that will massively help!

Comment: yes, I did ask a new question, the link is:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455038/how-to-call-function-in-parent-component-from-the-child-component . Sure, I created a sandbox for it: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ardinghelli-pjx7p?file=/src/components/Search.js . Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Place addFunc within the parent component and make your RenderItem function a React Functional component by exporting it. Then provide the addFunc as a function prop from parent component to RenderItem component. That way you can call the function within onClick event. Any of the parent states can be updated from the addFunc. You can supply necessary arguments to the function call as well.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask for, could you tell me a little bit more in detail? How do I change my function to a functional component? And how do I add the function props?
```constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.addFunc = this.addFunc.bind(this);
    }```
I did this, but when I call `this.addFunc` in my onclick, the function simply does not run. What am I missing here?