# How to call function in parent component from the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-state

I have a function called `addFunc` in my main Class. This class calls the `RenderItem` function to display a list of items. Each item has an `onClick` that should execute the `addFunc` function.

I am unable to call the `addFunc` function from within my `RenderItem` function because they are in different components. How do I get past this?

This is a summary of my code:

```
const selectedData = []

class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.addFunc = this.addFunc.bind(this);
    }

    addFunc(resultdata){
        console.log(resultdata)
        selectedData = [...selectedData, resultdata]
        console.log(selectedData)
      };
    render() {
      return (
            <ReactiveList
            componentId="results"
            dataField="_score"
            pagination={true}
            react={{
                and: ["system", "grouping", "unit", "search"]
            }}
            size={10}
            noResults="No results were found..."
            renderItem={RenderItem}
            />
      );


const RenderItem = (res, addFunc) => {
    let { unit, title, system, score, proposed, id } = {
      title: "maker_tag_name",
      proposed: "proposed_standard_format",
      unit: "units",
      system: "system",
      score: "_score",
      id: "_id"
    };
    const resultdata = {id, title, system, unit, score, proposed}

      return (
            <Button
                shape="circle"
                icon={<CheckOutlined />}
                style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}
                onClick={this.addFunc()}
            />
      );
  }
```

Comment: what is `ReactiveList` ?

Comment: I am building a search engine using an open-source software called Elasticsearch, which is what gives me the results of the search. Reactivesearch is just the UI to show the search results. I don't think it makes a difference in this case.

Comment: ok I sort of have something but im not sure how you're passing stuff down to `RenderItem` you have this ` renderItem={RenderItem}` but where do you pass props to it ?

Comment: I'm using an open-source software called ElasticSearch to upload my data and search through it. And for the UI, I use another open-source UI called ReactiveSearch (https://docs.appbase.io/docs/reactivesearch/v3/result/reactivelist/). So the results are from the database that I uploaded, and the RenderItem function calls them with the variables I define

Comment: I've uploaded my whole code in the CodeSandbox here if that helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ardinghelli-pjx7p?file=/src/components/Search.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `RenderItem` component with another component and then render it,

```
const Wrapper = cb => {
  return (res, triggerClickAnalytics) => (
    <RenderItem
      res={res}
      triggerClickAnalytics={triggerClickAnalytics}
      addFunc={cb}
    />
  );
};
```

and `renderItem` of `ReactiveList` would be: `renderItem={Wrapper(this.addFunc)}`
then `RenderItem` component would be

```
const RenderItem = ({ res, triggerClickAnalytics, addFunc }) => {
...
```

see sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-paper-337qz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much. You have no idea how long I've been trying this for. If you could, can you also help me add state to my function, so that it can display the data of all the results that is clicked? I have asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475163/how-to-update-array-using-state-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function defined in the parent as a prop to the child component

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
sayHello(name) => {
      console.log("Hello " + name)
}
render() {
        return <Child1 parentCallback = {this.sayHello}/>
    }
}
```

and then call it from the child component

```
class Child1 extends React.Component{
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.parentCallback("Foo")
}
render() { 
    return <span>child component</span>
    }
};
```

Comment: My child component is a functional component, not a class, so I dont think I can use `componentDidMount` in that. And also, what should the parentCallback be called in my case?